# How can I fix image positioning?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref} %- to zeby byly polskie znaki w bookmarkach + konwersja na utf8
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hypcap}

\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{2cm}{2cm}

\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{*}{}{}{}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother


\SetSectionFormatting[breakbefore]{chapter} {24pt plus5pt minus2pt}
{\FormatHangHeading{\fontsize{17}{17}\textbf}} {10pt plus3pt}
\SetSectionFormatting{section} {24pt plus5pt minus2pt}
{\FormatHangHeading{\fontsize{14}{14}\textbf}} {10pt plus3pt}
\SetSectionFormatting{subsection} {24pt plus5pt minus2pt}
{\FormatHangHeading{\fontsize{12}{12}\textbf}} {10pt plus3pt}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}%
}{}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\language 12345 % wyłącza dzielenie wyrazów
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\begin{titlepage}
\pdfbookmark{Strona tytułowa}{}
\includepdf[pages=1-]{strona_tytulowa.pdf}
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
\input{tresc.tex}
\input{bibliografia.tex}
\end{document}
```

tresc.tex:

```
\chapter{Bzdety}\label{rozdzial-bzdety}
W rozdziale \ref{rozdzial-bzdety} ze strony \pageref{rozdzial-bzdety} znajduje się obrazek \ref{obraz-jesien} na stronie \pageref{obraz-jesien}.

The first paragraph.

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{a.jpg}
    \caption[Opcjonalny skrócony opis do spisu obrazków]{Opis}
    \label{obraz-jesien}
\end{figure}


The second paragraph.
```

I expected something like:

```
The first paragraph.

[image]
[caption]

The second paragraph.
```

I got:

```
The first paragraph.    

The second paragraph.

[image]
[caption]
```

Image is at the very center of next page. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It will be easier to help you if you provide one.

Comment: This is the most duplicated question ever. Should the linked solutions not helped you please edit your question to state why and flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [a placement specifier](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures), e.g. you can use `[h]` as in the following:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
... figure contents ...
\end{figure}
```